# TypeError: books.map is not a function react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get my api to display the data but it keeps returning the error `books.map is not a function`. I'm aware my array is empty when the page loads but and it may need a `(books || [])` but that didn't work either.. any ideas?

I just want to be able to map the data into the table and then manipulate it. When I console.log(books) I get the data I want but the map doesn't work.

My code:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BookService from "../services/BookService";
import Books from "./Books";
import axios from "axios";

import { Table, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const BooksList = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [booksPerPage, setBooksPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      const res = await axios.post("http://nyx.vima.ekt.gr:3000/api/books");

      setBooks(res.data);

      console.log(setBooks);

      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchBooks();
  }, []);

  console.log(books, "BooksList");

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <h1 className="text-primary mb-3"> Books </h1>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="lg">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Book Author</th>
              <th>Book Pages</th>
              <th>Book Publication City</th>
              <th>Book Publication Country</th>
              <th>Book Publication Year</th>
              <th>Book Title</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {books.map(book => (
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{book.id}</td>
                <td>{book.book_pages}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default BooksList;
```

Comment: check does `res.data` return an array of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jay said, you should do `setBooks(res.data.books)` but I would also advise you to control an error from API result, if the API is down the front-end should know how to manage that errors instead of crashing. One way to do this is check whether the contetn of `res.data.books` is an array or not.

Your full code should look something like this:

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BookService from "../services/BookService";
import Books from "./Books";
import axios from "axios";

import { Table, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const BooksList = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [booksPerPage, setBooksPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      try {
        setError(false);
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await axios.post("http://nyx.vima.ekt.gr:3000/api/books");

        setBooks(res.data.books);

        console.log(setBooks);

        setLoading(false);
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true);
        setLoading(false);
        setBooks([]);
      }
    };

    fetchBooks();
  }, []);

  console.log(books, "BooksList");
  
  if(error) return <div>Error message</div>

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <h1 className="text-primary mb-3"> Books </h1>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="lg">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Book Author</th>
              <th>Book Pages</th>
              <th>Book Publication City</th>
              <th>Book Publication Country</th>
              <th>Book Publication Year</th>
              <th>Book Title</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {books.map(book => (
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{book.id}</td>
                <td>{book.book_pages}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default BooksList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the data like this because of all the response data are in the **books** properties

```
setBooks(res.data.books);
```